# DataTable iniciar com valor padrão

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Gostaria de um auxílio no meu problema. Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de iniciar o datatables com o campo search já preenchido com um valor default.
Tentei da seguinte maneira.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="search"').val('valor_default');
$('#table').DataTable();
});
```

Dessa maneira não funciona. Se puderem ajudar ou tiver alguma luz agradeço.

Comment: Acredito que a ordem do codigo ai deve ser primeiro o data table, e depois o preenchimento.

Comment: @RobsonBraga verdade, vou testar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além do que o *@Robson Braga* comentou (primeiro iniciar o componente), é preciso chamar duas ações da API do componente: `.search()` e `.draw()`, senão você apenas irá colocar um valor no input "search" sem filtrar a tabela.

Ficaria assim:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    var valor_padrao = 'Data 3';
    $('input[type="search"').val(valor_padrao);
    table.search(valor_padrao).draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: isso ai vlw pela ajuda